# Как связать репозиторий с хостингом?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Нужно связать репозиторий на bitbucket и веткой master с хостиногом. Подскажите, как это можно сделать или что почитать.

Comment: Что значит связать? И что за хостинг(есть ли шелл, cron)? Скрипт на хостинге, который периодически выполняет git pull подойдёт?

Comment: я просто делал  добавлял юзера..который  с которого делаю пул для обновления . дот нужного комита. ..

Comment: vp_arth Да идея ясна скрипт понадобится для примера.